# Can I see the last comment in my deleted answer?, or the deletion reason?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Yesterday I joined this comunity and posted an answer to this question

[29 - 1 = 30 – how?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52487/29-1-30-how)

The answer got like 7 upvotes, but then it was somehow deleted (among many others).

A comment was left regarding the deletion (I see part of it in the notifications bar), but since I can't see the answer the content of the comment (and the deletion reason) remains unknown to me.

Is there a way for me to get this info?

Comment: Not sure if there's any way for you to see it directly, but high rep users can see deleted content, so I can relay. The comment left as part of the deletion was: "*Since this is a "lateral thinking" answer to a non-[lateral-thinking] question, it has been removed.*"

Comment: @Alconja that's a surprise, didn't imagine such strict rules in a puzzling community, neither the upvoters (of that and the other removed answers) thought that way I believe, but if that's the way it is.., no problem

Comment: it's a little tricky... generally things are pretty relaxed, but we've had issues in the past with influxes of low quality content (especially driven by "lateral thinking" style questions, due to how the SE Hot Network Questions algorithm works), so sometimes moves are made to nip things in the bud... None of which is meant to imply that your answer was low quality, just a "slippery slope" answer, as it were. Hopefully you weren't put off and will stick around.

Comment: @Alconja thanks for the feedback, no problem with how you run the community, the hot network questions link looked like a nice start, that's why I added my answer, the "correct" one was already there (I upvoted it), just though that another view could be shared, nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see your own deleted answer by scrolling down to the bottom of the page.

If for some reason you can't find it, here's the bottom of it along with the comments:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: now, on a pc browser, I was able to see the deleted answer (it was impossible from the iPhone app), so now I'll leave a bit confused regarding these events (specially after seeing the other answers that remain undeleted in that question), but I guess I learned to post a spoiler with images and text (not an easy task), and also a new, flexible and tight, definition of lateral thinking

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your own deleted posts.
(You should have received the comment in your Inbox, as well.)
You may potentially have to refresh the page to clear the "This post has been deleted." banner, and see your deleted post in a pinkish background shading, probably near the bottom of the page.

Deleted *answers* should always be visible to you just by visiting the question's page (and, as noted, possibly refreshing the page).

Irrelevant to you, but in the interest of completeness:
Deleted *questions* can be seen if you have a link to them.  Recently deleted questions can be found via your Profile page, on the "Activity" tab, under "questions" — there is a link at the bottom which says "deleted recent questions" and (huge shocker here) gives links to any recently deleted questions you've posted.

Comment: Well, in the iPhone app none of those options seems to be easily available, I'll check it later in my computer, btw, thanks for the condescending answer

Comment: No condescension intended, and I'm not even sure what you took as condescending.  You're right about the limitations of the mobile app; it's frustratingly different from the full site, and if you're in it then deleted posts are indeed invisible. (My understanding of how comments on deletions work is that you should have gotten the comment in your Inbox, which I personally know is visible in the iPhone app; if that isn't working, that would be something interesting to look into.)